Passing the unit-test C#
We have a unit-test to pass.
[TestCase("P2W12P1937A", "W", "12", "1937", "A")]
[TestCase("P02K13P8732D", "K", "13", "8732", "D")]
[TestCase("P002Z14P3573B", "Z", "14", "3573", "B")]
public void GetSerialNumberDetails(string serialNumber, string expectedCountryCode, string expectedManufacturerCode, string expectedFactoryCode, string expectedStationCode)
{
    // Act
    UsingRanges.GetSerialNumberDetails(serialNumber, out string countryCode, out string manufacturerCode, out string factoryCode, out string stationCode);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(expectedCountryCode, Is.EqualTo(countryCode));
    Assert.That(expectedManufacturerCode, Is.EqualTo(manufacturerCode));
    Assert.That(expectedFactoryCode, Is.EqualTo(factoryCode));
    Assert.That(expectedStationCode, Is.EqualTo(stationCode));
}

Here we see that (expectedCountryCode) is right after “2”. expectedCountryCode is before “P” (two characters). expectedFactoryCode is 5-2 characters from the end. And expectedStationCode is the last character.
But my implementation doesn't pass for some reason.
public static void GetSerialNumberDetails(string serialNumber, out string countryCode, out string manufacturerCode, out string factoryCode, out string stationCode)
{
    // TODO #3-12. Analyze unit tests for the method, and add the method implementation.
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(serialNumber);

    string manufacturerCode1 = serialNumber[serialNumber.IndexOf('P', StringComparison.Ordinal) - 2].ToString();
        string manufacturerCode2 = serialNumber[serialNumber.IndexOf('P', StringComparison.Ordinal) - 1].ToString();

    countryCode = serialNumber[serialNumber.IndexOf('2', StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1].ToString();
    manufacturerCode = manufacturerCode1 + manufacturerCode2;
    factoryCode = serialNumber[^5..^2].ToString();
    stationCode = serialNumber[^1].ToString();
}

I know I'm looking for the manufacturerCode wrong, but it looks right.
results of all three tests:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

So have you stepped through the code in a debugger to work out which line is throwing the exception, and why? (Hint: what do you expect the result of serialNumber.IndexOf('P', ...) to be, and why are you then subtracting two from it?)

If the serialNumber starts with P, then IndexOf('P', ...) will be zero; you then subtract from that, giving a negative index ... so you're fetching the minus-two'th character from a string; what are you trying to do here?

Going from back to front seems to be the easier alternative. You are already doing that for half of the values. Why not for the remaining ones? So, it starts with stationCode: 1 place from back, followed by 4 places factory code, then 'P' (which could be a good thing to check for - just in case), then 2 places manufacturer code, then 1 countrycode. Done. If the code is smaller than 9 chars, you don't even need to bother trying ...

Btw: I would return a bool indicating validity of the out params (false in case of unexpected values / length etc) -- but that's unrelated to this.

Why you are getting the exception is already explained in comments - simply you need to debug your solution and see where the exception is thrown, inspect values of variables, etc.
For your assistance, I have come up with simple implementation to your problem. All the comments and explanations are alongside the code:
public static class UsingRanges
{
    public static void GetSerialNumberDetails(
        string serialNumber,
        out string countryCode,
        out string manufacturerCode,
        out string factoryCode,
        out string stationCode)
    {
        var firstP = serialNumber.IndexOf('P');
        var secondP = serialNumber.IndexOf('P', firstP + 1);
        var first2 = serialNumber.IndexOf('2');

        // Get character AFTER first "2"
        countryCode = serialNumber[(first2 + 1)..(first2 + 2)];
        // Get 2 characters BEFORE second "P"
        manufacturerCode = serialNumber[(secondP - 2)..secondP];
        // Get characters BETWEEN second "P" and second to last character
        factoryCode = serialNumber[(secondP + 1)..(serialNumber.Length - 1)];
        // Get last character.
        stationCode = serialNumber[(serialNumber.Length - 1)..];
    }
}

